# React and Leaflet - issue displaying a layer

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to use Leaflet on a React project.
My goal is actually very basic: just display a openstreetMap layer (without markers or stuff)

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';

class MyMap extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
      map:null,
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
        var map = L.map('map', {
            minZoom: 2,
            maxZoom: 20,
            layers: [L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'})],
            attributionControl: false,
        });
        return this.setState({
            map: map
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id='map'> </div>
        );
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyMap />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Each time I have the save problem to display the map:
it looks like this: (not all tiles displayed and they are superpositions issues):
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS2VH.png)

Is someone face to this problem or have any solutions ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you've loaded in Leaflet's stylesheet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css">
```

The shuffle of the tiles happens because either the stylesheet not loaded yet or Leaflet is executed after React is actually rendering the map target. What we can do is add a timeout for the initialization:

```js
class MyMap extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state ={
      map: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var map = L.map('map', {
          minZoom: 2,
          maxZoom: 20,
          layers: [L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'})],
          attributionControl: false,
      });
      map.fitWorld();
      return this.setState({
          map: map
      });
    }, 100)
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="map" style={{ height: 300 }}></div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyMap />,
  document.getElementById('View')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css">
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: I had the same problem. I forgot to include the Leaflet's stylesheet as you already mentioned. React Leaflet module doesn't include Leaflet's stylesheet and [here is the reason](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/75#issuecomment-232908434).

Comment: It definitely makes sense, although it's easy to forget. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Thank you! Indeed i forget to load the leaflet stylesheet. And with the setTimeOut(), it works perfectly

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.